# Scala: HashSet Intersection

Tags: scala, tuples, intersection, hashset

I have a number of 2000+ lines of (ID1 ID2), which separated by blank space each line from a text file. The size for both ID1&2 is 100.

```
  //My load file codes 
def loadFile(file:Iterator[String]):Set[(Int,Int)] = {

        val z1 = file.map(line =>line.split(" ") match {
           case Array(id1,id2)=>(id1.toInt,id2.toInt)
        }).toSet
        z1

  }
```

I load them as `Set(Tuples(ID1, ID2))`. As my set is more than 4 elements, it is indicated as a HashSet here.

```
myData = HashSet((15,88), (56,66), (92,68), (27,4), (84,14), (88,17), (6,47), (97,45), (96,41), (21,66), (65,10), (44,66), (2,9), (86,61),...)
```

The target of my code is to find **which ID2 has involved/contains/intersected in EVERY ID1**. Finally, print out the `ID2`, i.e. `(ID1_1,ID2_EVERYONE),(ID1_2,ID2_EVERYONE), (ID1_3,ID2_EVERYONE), (ID1_4,ID_EVERYONE), ... ,(ID1_100,ID2_EVERYONE)`

`print ID_EVERYONE`

**UPDATED**
Here to give a smaller group size of my example, for size= 5,

```
(1,5), (2,5), (3,5),(4,5),(5,5), 
(1,4), (2,4), (3,4),(4,4),(5,4), 
(5,4), (4,5)
```

For the condition: ID_1(from 1 to 5) they all recognize 4 and 5. And ID_1= 4&5 only allows knowing each other. Finally, print out ID 4&5.

**Updated V2**

```
(37,52), (37,37), (37,45), (37,14)
(52,37), (52,52), (52,45), (52,14)

(14,20), (14,14), (14,12), (14,4), (14,49), (14,91), (14,45), (14,54), (14,52), (14,37)

(45,45), (45,52), (45,14), (45,37)
```

From  @jwvh's codes:

> myData.groupMap(_.*1)(*._2).values.reduce( _ intersect _)

It helps to produce the data above. However, observe that *ID14* is knowing extra ID other than *ID 37,52,45 and itself*. Hence, *ID14* should be filtered out as well.

Comment: It sounds like maybe what you want is `myData.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).values.reduce(_ intersect _)` (Scala 2.13.x), but it's hard to tell. Could you provide sample input with expected output?

Comment: @jwvh Sorry about the confusion. For an example of a size of 5, (1,5), (2,5), (3,5),(4,5),(5,5), meaning every ID1 recognises ID2=5, hence printout 5. In my case there is multiple ID2 recognizes by all ID1.

Comment: OK, and did you try my suggestion? If it doesn't produce the desired results then maybe you can use that information to clarify your requirements, i.e. why what it does isn't what you need.

Comment: @jwvh I apply the code you provided, I think the answer is partially correct, but some of ID2 is wrong. I think the condition is insufficient, should add in another as **ID2 can ONLY recognize other ID2** as well. i.e.,
`(1,5), (2,5), (3,5),(4,5),(5,5), 
(1,4), (2,4), (3,4),(4,4),(5,4),
(5,4),(4,5)`
In this, from 1 to 5 they all know 4,5. Under this condition, 4 & 5 allows knowing each other. I hope my phasing won't make confusion to you! Thanks YA!

Comment: I ran my code over your sample and the result is `HashSet(5, 4)`. Why is that not correct? My recommendation is to stop trying to _describe_ what you want and put in the effort to **demonstrate** what you want. Use examples, not words. Re-edit your question (stop posting in the comments) and **show** expected results for a given set of inputs.

Comment: The code I posted 2 days ago produces the desired result for the posted example. Please post an example where the suggested solution gives the wrong results.

Comment: @jwvh Thank you for the comments! I had edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you wish to find the subset of ID2 which is "known" by all ID1 members but does not recognize any other ID2 member as an ID1 member
can u try something like that

```
    val id1Pointers : Map[Int,Set[Int]] = myData.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).toSet)
    val id2Optionals: Set[Int] = id1Pointers.values.reduce( _ intersect _)
    val finalId2 = id2Optionals.filter(id2 =>  (id1Pointers.getOrElse(id2,Set[Int]()).subsetOf(id2Optionals)))
    println(finalId2.mkString("&"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. This works perfectly for my case now! But can you briefly explain your `val finalId2`?

Comment: I filtered all the ID2 optional members that were pointed from all the ID1 members but as ID1 members had pointed on different ID2. Hope that helped